# What is the curing process for polymer concrete if it doesn't use any water?

Tags: civil-engineering, concrete

The curing process for regular cement concrete is sprinkling water fog or using a moisture retaining fabric. I was wondering what the process is for polymer concretes because they don't use any water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the curing process for ordinary concrete is a chemical reaction between the ingredients of the cement mix and water which is stirred into that mix. Water is sprinkled onto the curing concrete to make sure that enough water is available to make the curing reaction go to completion and also to cool the concrete, since the reaction releases heat.

In the case of polymer cement, "curing" is a chemical reaction between the resin and the curing agent which are mixed together before pouring. Sometimes the curing agent is air, which fuels the chemical reaction that causes the resin to turn into a solid, and in some cases the air-curing chemical reaction is assisted by moisture in the air.